# Microdata for offers

Tags: html, microdata

Can I have multiple offers for different products on a single page?  I read some article saying that I cannot use multiple offer snippets on a page. I wanted to see if somebody knows more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you might want to look at http://schema.org/AggregateOffer for an example. Additionally there is a similar post which might help you with an answer at [How to approach schema.org microdata markup in an product offers aggregation page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141179/how-to-approach-schema-org-microdata-markup-in-an-product-offers-aggregation-pag)

I hope this is of use to you.