# Is there a way to format microdata for a single review with aggregate ratings?

Tags: microdata

I can't for the life of me figure out how to structure microdata for a page that has a single review but multiple ratings so that google will correctly interpret it.

Here's some sample markup, which seems legal but google ignores the rating part:

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Executive
    Anvil</span>
<span itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate"><span itemprop="rating">4.4</span> stars, based on <span itemprop="count">89 </span> votes</span>
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review">
<span itemprop="itemreviewed">Executive
    Anvil</span>
    Reviewed by <span itemprop="reviewer">Ulysses Grant</span> on
    <time itemprop="dtreviewed" datetime="2009-01-06">Jan 6</time>.
    <span itemprop="summary">Delicious, tasty pizza in Eastlake!</span>
    <span itemprop="description">L'Amourita serves up traditional wood-fired Neapolitan-style pizza, 
      brought to your table promptly and without fuss. An ideal neighborhood pizza joint.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to approach schema.org microdata markup in an product offers aggregation page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141179/how-to-approach-schema-org-microdata-markup-in-an-product-offers-aggregation-pag)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! It turns out I should be using schema.org.