# Additional Product Info on a page

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm developing a page that contains multiple products on it as recommendations on a product page.  Some of the recommendations are not present on the page unless the user takes an action, but they are preloaded in the DOM.  Does the schema.org data on these products muddy the water for SEO or is there presence benign?

Comment: Asking for possible effects on SEO is off-topic here. It’s on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Thanks,  I think I got most of what I need from this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141179/how-to-approach-schema-org-microdata-markup-in-an-product-offers-aggregation-pag?rq=1